# sidenav fixed while body scrolls

Tags: jquery, css

I have been working on this for quite sometime and no luck yet. I have tried different solutions that I found here and elsewhere but nothing worked so far.

I have a fiddle example here:

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lucky500/75cxuz6a/)

```css
#navbarsExampleDefault {
  outline: 5px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -50%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
}

.active-state {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
}

.navbar {
  outline: 5px solid red;
}
```

and what I am trying to do is to have my sidenav fixed, while the body scrolls. I also want the nav to stay fixed, so I am able to click on the toggler to close the sidenav.

right now, as it stands, the sidenav and the body scrolls together. Worse case scenario, I would at least like to have the sidenav fixed and the whole body to scroll. and I would find an alternative solution to close the sidenav.

Any help would be appreciated it.

PS. If I remove the right: -50% position, the sidenav works as intended, it sticks to the top. But I want to have the sidenav fixed to the top, and to the side and of the body -50%.

Comment: Only the body vertically scrolls for me. What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Try `z-index: 1;`

Comment: I am using Chrome, and z-index: 1 doesn't do anything

Comment: Do you have your answer already? In your example it is not clear if you wanted a fixed top navigation or a SIDE navigation. I got a few examples in my archive. If you still need some help please let me know

Comment: I think this is getting closer: https://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/75cxuz6a/9/ BUT I stopped working on it because I honestly think you are going down the wrong road, you should refactor your whole HTML and approach it differently

Comment: Hey @Babulaas, what I want is the body to be scrollable and the sidenav to be fixed at the top. and no, I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: Hey Jonas, That is indeed pretty close to the effect that I am looking for. And to be honest with you, I don't like this design either, but this was what it was asked. If no other solution comes up, I will accept yours as it is better than what I have so far.

Comment: I would create a layout with header and sidebar and then have it so that just the content scrolls in a scrollable div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have commented above how in my opinion you should refactor your HTML, with that I am not commenting on the design, but strictly the code. You can keep the design as is and just refactor the HTML alone.

Start with a smaller case and get it to work the way you want and only then add all the icons, border-radiuses and other little touches, that way it will be much easier to get everything set up.

If I understood correctly what you're asking for, I'd say you could start with something like this:

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
 $(".container").toggleClass("menu-open");
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  transition: margin-left 125ms ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  transition: margin-left 125ms ease-in-out;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.navbar .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #BADA55;
  padding: 40px;
}

.container.menu-open {
  margin-left: -200px;
}

.container.menu-open {
  margin-left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    NavBar
    <button>
    Toggle Menu
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown">
      Dropdown
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <h2>I add some content to make the scrollbar appear</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, eaque. Esse quidem aliquid laudantium ea, perspiciatis praesentium incidunt cupiditate autem excepturi dolorum officia voluptatem quasi ducimus non tenetur blanditiis, ipsum quam voluptates eveniet est. Magnam neque, quo error, ullam temporibus earum, architecto omnis cum totam facilis aut expedita tempora? Iste aliquam, libero itaque, animi alias pariatur quos iure recusandae neque quo. Assumenda consequuntur doloremque cumque rerum aperiam, blanditiis incidunt voluptatibus! Hic maxime saepe nostrum eligendi, eveniet optio temporibus earum ipsum sunt et, qui voluptatem odit corporis natus animi inventore non expedita autem. Facilis ea quam perferendis dignissimos beatae! Aperiam culpa porro impedit ullam aliquam officiis nesciunt itaque pariatur sapiente, vitae quos quibusdam fugit exercitationem eaque suscipit unde molestias, nobis natus vel non doloribus ab quidem saepe accusamus explicabo. Tenetur mollitia voluptate quae impedit sed aliquam quos tempore, necessitatibus ipsa repellendus cum ipsum at unde cupiditate eos eaque ratione vitae animi quisquam nisi, harum obcaecati nobis! Magni quo praesentium soluta accusantium quae officiis dolor ab eum et, debitis sit eos mollitia ex consequatur cum sapiente dolores iste doloremque ullam molestiae officia voluptatum! Quisquam enim quibusdam placeat porro, aut commodi illum, quos nostrum fugit a eligendi hic, sint voluptates. Et, quaerat, a.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, eaque. Esse quidem aliquid laudantium ea, perspiciatis praesentium incidunt cupiditate autem excepturi dolorum officia voluptatem quasi ducimus non tenetur blanditiis, ipsum quam voluptates eveniet est. Magnam neque, quo error, ullam temporibus earum, architecto omnis cum totam facilis aut expedita tempora? Iste aliquam, libero itaque, animi alias pariatur quos iure recusandae neque quo. Assumenda consequuntur doloremque cumque rerum aperiam, blanditiis incidunt voluptatibus! Hic maxime saepe nostrum eligendi, eveniet optio temporibus earum ipsum sunt et, qui voluptatem odit corporis natus animi inventore non expedita autem. Facilis ea quam perferendis dignissimos beatae! Aperiam culpa porro impedit ullam aliquam officiis nesciunt itaque pariatur sapiente, vitae quos quibusdam fugit exercitationem eaque suscipit unde molestias, nobis natus vel non doloribus ab quidem saepe accusamus explicabo. Tenetur mollitia voluptate quae impedit sed aliquam quos tempore, necessitatibus ipsa repellendus cum ipsum at unde cupiditate eos eaque ratione vitae animi quisquam nisi, harum obcaecati nobis! Magni quo praesentium soluta accusantium quae officiis dolor ab eum et, debitis sit eos mollitia ex consequatur cum sapiente dolores iste doloremque ullam molestiae officia voluptatum! Quisquam enim quibusdam placeat porro, aut commodi illum, quos nostrum fugit a eligendi hic, sint voluptates. Et, quaerat, a.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, eaque. Esse quidem aliquid laudantium ea, perspiciatis praesentium incidunt cupiditate autem excepturi dolorum officia voluptatem quasi ducimus non tenetur blanditiis, ipsum quam voluptates eveniet est. Magnam neque, quo error, ullam temporibus earum, architecto omnis cum totam facilis aut expedita tempora? Iste aliquam, libero itaque, animi alias pariatur quos iure recusandae neque quo. Assumenda consequuntur doloremque cumque rerum aperiam, blanditiis incidunt voluptatibus! Hic maxime saepe nostrum eligendi, eveniet optio temporibus earum ipsum sunt et, qui voluptatem odit corporis natus animi inventore non expedita autem. Facilis ea quam perferendis dignissimos beatae! Aperiam culpa porro impedit ullam aliquam officiis nesciunt itaque pariatur sapiente, vitae quos quibusdam fugit exercitationem eaque suscipit unde molestias, nobis natus vel non doloribus ab quidem saepe accusamus explicabo. Tenetur mollitia voluptate quae impedit sed aliquam quos tempore, necessitatibus ipsa repellendus cum ipsum at unde cupiditate eos eaque ratione vitae animi quisquam nisi, harum obcaecati nobis! Magni quo praesentium soluta accusantium quae officiis dolor ab eum et, debitis sit eos mollitia ex consequatur cum sapiente dolores iste doloremque ullam molestiae officia voluptatum! Quisquam enim quibusdam placeat porro, aut commodi illum, quos nostrum fugit a eligendi hic, sint voluptates. Et, quaerat, a.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, That should get me out of this current jam.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 simple demos for you.

The first with jquery (slide in sticky menu):

http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Floating-Sticky-Slide-Menu-Plugin-With-jQuery-Slide-Menu.html

Another is a sticky sidebar menu. 
this one is very basic but if you don't want to use jquery,
you can you use this one and use html5/css3 animation to slide in/out the menu:

https://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few edits to your CSS (none to the HTML although the above posters recommendations on how to organise your code shouldnt go unheeded)

https://jsfiddle.net/3s425ufa/

I changes from transform to transition as it has better support and less scope for misinterpretation by browsers. I hope this helps.

```
#main-container{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
#navbarsExampleDefault {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: -50%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  transition: right 1s linear;
}

.active-state #navbarsExampleDefault {
  right:0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```